# How can i get the info of the cardview i click on to send it to the next activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-cardview

I'm making an application were i show a list of cardviews using a recyclerview and i want to be able to make a detail activity of the cardview the user clicks but i dont know how to send the item that is clicked to the next activity.

Here u can see my adapter:

/**
 * Created by alberto on 18/05/16.
 */

```
public class EmpresasAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<EmpresasAdapter.EmpresasViewHolder>
    implements ItemClickListener{
private final Context context;
private List<Empresas> items;

public EmpresasAdapter(Context context, List<Empresas> items) {
    this.context = context;
    this.items = items;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return items.size();
}

@Override
public EmpresasViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.empresa_card, viewGroup, false);
    return new EmpresasViewHolder(v, this);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(EmpresasViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    // Item procesado actualmente
    Empresas currentItem = items.get(i);

    viewHolder.nombrep.setText(currentItem.getNombre());
    viewHolder.descripcionp.setText(currentItem.getDescripcionC());
    viewHolder.franquiciap.setText(currentItem.getModalidad()+" | "+currentItem.getFranquicia());
   // Cargar imagen
    Glide.with(context)
            .load(currentItem.getImagen())
            .into(viewHolder.imagenp);
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
    // Imagen a compartir entre transiciones
    View sharedImage = view.findViewById(R.id.imagenp);
    EmpresaDetalle.launch(
            (Activity) context, position, sharedImage);
}

/**
 * View holder para reciclar elementos
 */
public static class EmpresasViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
        implements View.OnClickListener {
    // Views para un curso
    public ImageView imagenp;
    public TextView nombrep;
    public TextView descripcionp;
    public TextView franquiciap;
    // Interfaz de comunicación
    public ItemClickListener listener;

    public EmpresasViewHolder(View v, ItemClickListener listener) {
        super(v);
        nombrep = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.nombrep);
        descripcionp = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.descripcionp);
        franquiciap = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.Franquiciap);


        imagenp = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imagenp);
        v.setOnClickListener(this);

        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        listener.onItemClick(v, getAdapterPosition());
    }


}
```

Comment: which item want to send in next Activity?

Comment: i would like to get the position in the array of the cardview so i can get all the info i want to show (The same info that i show in the cardview + something more) and use it in my detail view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the items as extra to the intent for launching the DetailedActivty:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
    // Imagen a compartir entre transiciones
    View sharedImage = view.findViewById(R.id.imagenp);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, DetailedActivty.class)
    intent.putExtra(nombrep, NOMBREP_EXTRA);
    intent.putExtra(descripcionp, DESCRIPCIONP_EXTRA);
    intent.putExtra(franquiciap, FRANQUICIAP_EXTRA);
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: it's there a way to get the array position of the card i click? so i can put it in the extra, i'm asking this because i want to show more infor than the one of the card in the detail activity. To get the info in the second activity i have to use getExtra() right?

Comment: Yes, thats right. In the second activity you should get the info by getExtra().

Comment: i have the problem that when i use getnombreextra and print it in the textview it shows like com.example.babus.extra.NOMBRE

Comment: Upload the code you used for setting and getting the extra.

Comment: i got the items with bundles instead of get extra   ( Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();)

Answer (score 1):

Change your onCreateViewHolder like this

```
public EmpresasViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
   View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.empresa_card, viewGroup, false);
   v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener{
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v){
          //you have the cardView in v;
          //you can access the child view of your cardView by referring to v
          //if you want to get the position you can do it here.
          //Create an intent with the collected data an d start the activity

       }
   });
   return new EmpresasViewHolder(v, this);
}
```

You can do this in `onBindView()` method too. Position is easily accessible with this method. But that does not mean that you can't have the position in the former method. You can. But I've not described it. Will do if you want.

```
//to do this its easier if you have assigned and id to the cardView in XML and store the cardView in the viewHOlder
//getting cardView
CardView cardView=holder.cardView;
cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        //position is easily availble now.
        //you can access the rest of the views
        //create youtr intent and start the activity
    }
});
```